# Problem with execAndWait interceptor, SESSION lost

Tags: interceptor

I am using execAndWait interceptor and it seems the session is lost after the interceptor..

my code is - struts-lcms.xml

...

```
<action name="testAction" class="com.lcms.presentation.TestAction">

   <interceptor-ref name="execAndWait"></interceptor-ref>
    <param  name="delay">3000</param>
    <param  name="delaySleepInterval">50</param>  
   <result name="wait" type="tiles">tiles.ques</result>  
   <result name="success" type="tiles">tiles.ques</result>
   <result name="diag" type="redirectAction">diagnosticAction</result>
</action>
```

...

If I remove the interceptor code then it takes me to the question page (tiles.ques) .. However, with the interceptor the session is null..

This code in execute method in the TestAction file

```
  SessionObject sess = (SessionObject)getSession().getAttribute(LcmsConstants.SESSION_OBJECT);
```

it gives the session correctly if the interceptor is not used.. however, if the interceptor code is used then it throws NULL pointer exception..

Please tell me how to overcome this problem..

Answer (score 2):

implements SessionAware

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor.html

Important: Because the action will be running in a seperate thread, you can't use ActionContext because it is a ThreadLocal. This means if you need to access, for example, session data, you need to implement SessionAware rather than calling ActionContext.getSesion().

Answer (score 0):

mention in struts.xml as

```
<interceptor-stack name="loadingStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="completeStack" />
    <interceptor-ref name="execAndWait">
        <param name="delay">1000</param>
        <param name="delaySleepInterval">500</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
</interceptor-stack>

<interceptor-ref name="loadingStack"/>
<result name="wait">ETAX/TDS/wait.jsp</result>
```

it is working fine on my machine